# How to create such a raster shading?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Look at this pic:

[image]

How Do I create in Illustrator those areas which you find in the poster between the blue and the yellow areas. they are horizontally blue-yellow striped

thanks

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved as a texture fill, or a layer with horizontal lines that has a layer mask. (a single line can be created and then duplicated using for instance "transform")

My opinion is that this is actually a hand-inked drawing which was then scanned and traced, perhaps then duplicated 3 times (for dark blue, light blue, and red), and then certain portions from each color were masked or removed.

the image can be thought of as a yellow page, with three colors: dark blue, light blue, and red layer and the yellow show through transparent areas.

some useful Google terms: 3 color posterization illustrator

Comment: In illustrator for instance there allready are a few line-patterns available.
if you activate the Swatches palette got to the options button (upper right corner of the palette)
`Open Swatch Library` > `Patterns` > `BASIC GRAPHICS_Lines`. The color is easily changed via `Edit Colors`.
Just out of curiosity: Were you by any chance reading this? http://youthoughtwewouldntnotice.com/blog3/?p=8958

Comment: that sounds good - how do I apply those graphic lines to my shapes? hehe no - I'm tracing the very same picture cause I want to print it as a poster with a different text

Answer (score 1):

The posted image is actually quite some work. As suggested, I too think it is handdrawn and then inked in Illustrator. If you are trying to practice your shading, there is a [website](http://www.dubster.com/obamafy/online.php5) with a plugin that does this. The shading is not nearly as good, but maybe it can give you a hint on how to plan your illustration.

[image]

If you just want the exact same poster, why not **buy a print from the original artist**?